# How do I loop over Excel files in a shared drive and make/save changes on each of them?

Tags: vba, excel

I'm in a bit of a time crunch, and my beginner VBA skills are failing me.

I have 900 files in a shared drive folder and I need a macro to open each file, center and align a few cells, save and close, and move to the next file.

Could someone help me in writing this code? I have the formatting section down.

Thank you so much!

```
    Range("B45:B51").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
With Selection
    .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
    .VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
    .WrapText = False
    .Orientation = 0
    .AddIndent = False
    .IndentLevel = 0
    .ShrinkToFit = False
    .ReadingOrder = xlContext
    .MergeCells = False
End With
Range("M45:M48").Select
With Selection
    .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
    .VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
    .WrapText = False
    .Orientation = 0
    .AddIndent = False
    .IndentLevel = 0
    .ShrinkToFit = False
    .ReadingOrder = xlContext
    .MergeCells = False
End With
Range("C45:C51").Select
With Selection
    .HorizontalAlignment = xlLeft
    .VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
    .WrapText = False
    .Orientation = 0
    .AddIndent = False
    .IndentLevel = 0
    .ShrinkToFit = False
    .ReadingOrder = xlContext
    .MergeCells = False
End With
Range("N45:N48").Select
With Selection
    .HorizontalAlignment = xlLeft
    .VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
    .WrapText = False
    .Orientation = 0
    .AddIndent = False
    .IndentLevel = 0
    .ShrinkToFit = False
    .ReadingOrder = xlContext
    .MergeCells = False
End With
```

Comment: We sincerely suggest you post your working code for the formatting. You have the duty of, at the very least, providing us with some canvas to paint on, buddy. :) Off the top of my head, this is a simple application of either `Dir` or `FSO`.

Comment: Use the idea of **[FileSystemObject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6tkce7xa(v=vs.84).aspx)** as `Application.FileSearch` no longer exist from Office 2007. Then just make 2 Subs (with Range as input) for the formatting (appears to be only have 2 unique styles you displayed). Call these Subs for each file to be opened in loop.

Comment: [**This question**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10380312/loop-through-files-in-a-folder-using-vba) should help you with how to loop through the files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have a list of the names of the files you want to open?
If you have it you can loop trough it setting a workbook as the name of each file.

Es.

```
Dim x as integer
Dim selection, nameofthefile as variant
Dim wk1 As Workbook
Dim sh1 As Worksheet    
Dim wk2 As Workbook
Dim sh2 As Worksheet

Set wk1 = Workbooks("this file.xlsx")
Set sh1 = wk1.Worksheet("name of the sheet with the list")
For x = 1 To 900 
If Cells(x , 1) <> "" Then
 selection = Cells(x , 1)
 nameofthefile = "Your path" & ".xlsx"
 Workbooks.Open Filename:=nameofthefile
 Set wk2 = Workbooks(selection & ".xlsx")
 Set sh2 = wk2.Worksheets("Name of the sheet you want to use")
 sh1.activate
 Range("B45:B51").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
With Selection
.HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
.VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
.WrapText = False
.Orientation = 0
.AddIndent = False
.IndentLevel = 0
.ShrinkToFit = False
.ReadingOrder = xlContext
.MergeCells = False
End With
Range("M45:M48").Select
With Selection
.HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
.VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
.WrapText = False
.Orientation = 0
.AddIndent = False
.IndentLevel = 0
.ShrinkToFit = False
.ReadingOrder = xlContext
.MergeCells = False
End With
Range("C45:C51").Select
With Selection
.HorizontalAlignment = xlLeft
.VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
.WrapText = False
.Orientation = 0
.AddIndent = False
.IndentLevel = 0
.ShrinkToFit = False
.ReadingOrder = xlContext
.MergeCells = False
End With
Range("N45:N48").Select
With Selection
.HorizontalAlignment = xlLeft
.VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
.WrapText = False
.Orientation = 0
.AddIndent = False
.IndentLevel = 0
.ShrinkToFit = False
.ReadingOrder = xlContext
.MergeCells = False
End With
Application.CutCopyMode = False
wk1.Close SaveChanges:=True
End If
Next
Set wk2 = Nothing
Set sh2 = Nothing
```

it's only an example but it should work with a list. Tell us more